# Map intervals defined in data frame to vector

Tags: r, intervals

I have a data frame with intervals definition:

```
ints <- read.table(header=T, sep=";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = 'NA', text="
minValue;minOperato;maxValue;maxOperator;class
3914;>=;NA;NA;[3914,Inf)
NA;NA;1373;<;[ -Inf,1373)
1373;>=;1806;<;[1373,1806)
2777;>=;3914;<;[2777,3914)
1806;>=;2777;<;[1806,2777)
")
```

And a second data frame with value `x` and binary variable `y`:

```
sd <- data.frame(x = runif(1000) * 5000, y = as.integer(runif(1000) > .5))
```

Now, I would like to get number of zeros and ones in `sd` data frame for every interval and merge results to `ints` data frame.

I thought I will use `cut`:

```
breaks <- c(-Inf, ints$minValue[order(ints$minValue)], Inf)
breaks <- breaks[!is.na(breaks)]
out <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(cut(sd$x, breaks, right = FALSE), sd$y))
```

Unfortunately, intervals in `out` do not match with intervals in my `ints` data frame (are represented differently), so I cannot join `out` to `ints`.

I know that I could probably generate some sql using `sqldf` package or recode `ints$x` in some loop, but this would be slow.

Comment: You might want to add the parameter `dig.lab = 4` to cut to precent decimal notation.

Comment: @lukeA Cool, this will work for this case, but is not generic, right?

Comment: Hm well, you could raise it to `50` or to `nchar(max(unlist(ints[, c(1,3)]), na.rm = TRUE))`, or what did you mean?

Comment: I do not have numbers in `ints` under control - could be big integers, extremely small numbers with different number of decimal digits. I think if will accommodate all situations if I set `dig.lab` to 50 or it can break in some scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to replace your intervals by a simple id ( a sequence). This should be done for ints and out data.frames. Each id identify one interval. Once you do this the merge is straightforward.

```
## first I extract the intevals from ints in ordered manner
id <- !is.na(ints$minValue)&!is.na(ints$maxValue)
class_factor <- 
  c(ints$class[which(is.na(ints$minValue))],
     ints$class[id][order(ints$minValue[id])],
     ints$class[which(is.na(ints$maxValue))])

## add an id column that identify each interval in ints data.frame
ints <- merge(data.frame(class=class_factor,id = seq_along(class_factor)),ints)

##  Do same thing in out uisng lables=FALSE  as a cut argument
out <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(cut(sd$x, breaks, right = FALSE,
         labels=FALSE), sd$y))  ## here the trick 

## merge ints and out 
merge(out,ints,by.x=0,by.y="id")

#     Row.names   0   1        class minValue minOperato maxValue maxOperator
#   1         1 132 146 [ -Inf,1373)       NA       <NA>     1373           <
#   2         2  45  38  [1373,1806)     1373         >=     1806           <
#   3         3  98  99  [1806,2777)     1806         >=     2777           <
#   4         4  98 110  [2777,3914)     2777         >=     3914           <
#   5         5 125 109   [3914,Inf)     3914         >=       NA        <NA>
```